# How can I check whether an AWS CLI --dry-run would have succeeded in script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I use various bash scripts to simplify day-to-day operations. Sometimes I run them having forgotten to acquire a session token, so I thought I'd add a few `--dry-run` commands early on in the script. I had expected that an operation outputting:

```
A client error (DryRunOperation) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set.
```

...would exit with `0` - after all, it has been successful in terms of the parameters supplied - but it exits with `255`.

The problem gets worse when you see that the output when you don't have permission to run a command exits with the same error code `255`:

```
A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Is the only solution to (yuck) check the actual output for the value "Request would have succeeded", or is there a more elegant solution?  I can't see the logic behind this at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to inspect the output.

Comment: It does answer the question. `Is the only solution to (yuck) check the actual output for the value "Request would have succeeded", or is there a more elegant solution?` The answer is that there is not a more elegant solution, they have to inspect the output.

Comment: Your answer looked like a comment, sorry. It seems that you are right. I will remove my comment.